# RexEg Pattern to Exclude Using the Retour Plugin

Tags: regex, plugin-retour

The Retour plugin has this setting: *Exclude Patterns - Regular expressions to match URLs that should be excluded from Retour.*

How would I exclude images (jpg and png) from being handled by Retour? My statistics are full of 404s from old Asset transforms that I used before switching to the Imager plugin.

I tried adding this (which I found here: https://regexr.com/2ukfb): `(http:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z\.\/_-]+.png|http:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z\.\/_-]+.jpg)`

But that didn't seem to work. Images with a 404 were still logged in the Statistics section of Retour. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RegEx is only the URI part; so something like `(.*.png|.*.jpg)` is probably what you want.

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks Andrew!